# How many possible passcode in 6-digit passcode that contains exactly four odd digits (can't be repeated)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Where each element can be any digit from 0 to 9.

Checking if I did it correctly,

$5*4*5*4*3*2$ = 2,400

5, 4 being evens

5, 4, 3, 2 being odd digits

Total # = $15*2,400$ = **36,000 possibilities**.

Comment: You did not explain where the $15$ comes from, but once you do then yes your answer would be correct and complete.

Comment: In this way you are putting the even digits in a fixed position, and so the odd ones. That's wrong

Comment: @zar notice the $15$ in $15\cdot 2400$.  Yes, $2400$ is the answer if the evens and odds are in fixed positions (e.g. both evens first).  The OP accounted for that by multiplying the result by $\binom{6}{2}=15$

Comment: Oh, I see it now.

Comment: As JMoravitz said, you should have explained that the factor of $15$ accounts for the $\binom{6}{2}$ ways of selecting the positions of the even digits.  Another way:  Select two of the five even digits in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, four of the five odd digits in $\binom{5}{4}$ ways, then arrange the six selected digits in $6!$ ways to obtain $\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{4}6! = 36,000$ possible passcodes.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it:

Pick your two different even digits ($_5C_2 = 10$), pick which two spaces they go in ($_6C_2 = 15$) and which order they appear in ($2$).

Then arrange four odd digits in the spaces that remain ($5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 120$).

This gives $36000$ codes.